# Calculating retail price to hit required margin - including a cost which depends on retail price

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a pricing rule, which dictates that of retail price, margin must be 20%. I have the cost price and the required margin, I need to calculate the (suggested) retail price.

The formula would look like this, I believe, where 20 is the required margin:

$retailprice=100*cost/(100-20)$

Reasonably straight-forward, even for a math-moron like myself.

Now I run into problems.

In some jurisdictions, there is something called MarginVAT, which means you have to pay a 25% VAT of your margin. This is effectively a cost - but a cost you can only calculate once you know the retail price.

MarginVAT is defined like this:

$marginVAT=(RetailPrice-Cost)*(marginVatPct/100)$

Also not too complicated.

But now I need to combine the two, creating a formula to calculate the suggested retail price, taking marginVAT into consideration.

- VAT rate: 25%
- Required Margin: 20%

I think the formula looks something like this:

$retailprice = (100x(cost+(retailprice-cost)*(25/100))) / (100-20)$

1. Does that look correct?
2. How can I make that simpler - into something I can actually turn into computer code?

*Ps. My math skills are quite poor, and my skills in describing math in English terms are quite poor as well, so please excuse me if I made some stupid errors.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do to make it simpler it to write numbers as numbers, rather than percentages, to get rid of those extraneous $100$'s.  Another is to assign variables.

Let $p$ be the retail price, $c$ the original cost, $v$ be the VAT rate, and $t$ be the tax.  If the margin is $20\%$ of the cost plus the tax, we have $$p=1.25(c+t)$$  Also, we know $$t=v(p-c)=vp-vc$$  Substituting the second equation into the first, we find $$p = 1.25(c+vp-vc)\\
p(1-1.25v)=1.25c(1-v)\\
p=\frac{1.25(1-v)}{1-1.25v}c
p=\frac{1-v}{.8-v}c$$

In the example where the VAT rate is $25\%$ this gives $$p=\frac{.75}{.55}c\approx1.3636c$$ and the markup is $36.36\%$ of the cost.

If the cost of an item is $100$, then the sales price will be $136.37$ and the VAT will be $.25\cdot36.37=9.09$.  The margin is $27.28$ which is $20\%$ of $136.37$, except for a little roundoff error.

Comment: Great answer. It works - but one thing still irks me. I don't understand how you go to the 1.25. I assume it is because 0.2 (the margin vat) * 1.25 = 1. But I am not quite sure how you arrived at that. Can you elaborate on that? What if the marginVAT was 10? How would I get to the value that is now 1.25? I assume if the marginVAT was 10, the 1.25 value would become 1.11 - but I am honestly not quite sure how to calculate it - or if I am right.

Comment: You had it in the body of your question:  $\frac{100}{100-20}=1.25$  It depends only on the required margin, not the VAT.  I gathered that the $20\%$ margin was fixed, so I didn't make it a variable.  Is it clear now?

Comment: Very clear, thank you very much. :)